# How to use OracleMembershipProvider in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle11g

As per the suggestions in my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380924/using-oracle-database-for-the-default-asp-net-mvc-application), I installed all the Oracle providers in the database (by running all the sql files). I am trying to figure out how to tweak the default ASP.NET MVC2 sample (the one that gets created on a new project in VS) to use Oracle database. But I could not still figure out how to use `OracleMembershipProvider` instead of default membership provider.

P.S I installed the ODAC (Universal Installer version) and I could access the database from a simple ASP.NET application.

EDIT: I tried to add   in   section of , but am getting a configuration error:

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

Comment: Please take a look at tutorial - Using Oracle Providers for ASP.NET

Comment: @AVD I tried it on web form ASP.NET application. It is working fine. But there appears to be some problem with ASP.NET MVC and there are no help for this.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://dotnetslackers.com/IIS/re-60499_What_is_It_is_an_error_to_use_a_section_registered_as_allowDefinition_MachineToApplication_beyond_application_level.aspx) provides some information on the allowDefinition error. There are also a number of SO posts that describe this error. You may want to look at them as well and see what worked for those folks.