# Add oracle database in asp.net (mvc) models

Tags: asp.net, oracle, model-view-controller

I have to install Oracle Developer tools for Visual Studio 2017
also I have odac 12c and when I try to connect MVC and Oracle, in models do not show Oracle database

https://ibb.co/fG45Jw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Oracle database for the default ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380924/using-oracle-database-for-the-default-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: which version on VS , community, pro or ent?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2017 Community Edition doesn't support yet with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio.

Refer this article https://community.oracle.com/thread/4009365?start=30&tstart=0